# What is the meaning \r carriage return and \f form feed in Java?

Tags: java

What is the meaning of `\r` carriage return and `/f` form feed in Java? Can anyone give a small example of when we have to use these types of symbols?

```
System.out.println("hello world \r rafter \n nafter \f fafter");
```

I don't know what is what in that above.

The output I got is:

```
hello world 
 r-after 
 n-after  f-after
```

I got `\r` as new line and `\n` for new line and with `\f` a box appears for me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You rarely use either of them (in isolation) in modern applications.

`\r` ([carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)) is what it sounds like **if** you're familiar with old-fashioned manual typewriters: It moves the "carriage" (the roll the paper is fed through) back to the beginning of the line. On a terminal (or similar), it moves the output point back to the beginning of the line, without moving down a line (usually).

`\f` is (as you said) a [*formfeed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed), it tells old-fashioned printers to start a new page. In computer documents, it's sometimes used to indicate a page break.

Rounding things out, there's also line feed (aka "newline"): `\n`. This means "move down a line." In some terminals, it just moves down a line without doing a carriage return; on others, it does both.

`\n` (LF, newline) is the standard text file line break on *nix and derived operating systems. `\r\n` (CRLF) is the standard text file line break on DOS and Windows. Back in the day, `\r` (on its own) was the standard line break in text files on the Mac, prior to Mac OS X (which is *nix-derived).

Answer (score 14):

To see the difference you must run your code from a command prompt. Eclipse's Console (and similar for other IDEs) does not simulate the behavior of a full TTY terminal and will move to the next line for both `\r` and `\n`. On the command line, however, `\r` will only move the cursor back to the beginning of the *current* line. This is very convenient when you want to show live progress of your program without scrolling.

The form-feed signal is harder to predict and not as useful. It may have the effect of clearing the terminal window in some cases.

Comment: Yes , inside the console on Eclipse \r work similar \n, and you can't see the difference of those Escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Carriage return and form feed are terminal or printer control characters and have no meaning whatsoever in Java.

In a terminal emulation, when you print a \r, the next character will possibly get printed at the first row of the *current* line (overwriting what is there already).

A form feed, when printed to a terminal may or may not clear the screen. On a printer, it should cause the current page to get ejected, so that printing continues on a new page.

But, as said before, neither the terminal (emulation) nor the printer do care whther the control character was printed by a Java program.

Answer (score 0):

`\f` is similar to `\n`, the difference is that the new line gets indented.

eg: "hello it was \f great meeting you"

it gives output:

```
 hello it was 
              great meeting you
```