# A question about \r in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a string with a regular expression

---

```
reg = ".*\\r.*";
str = "h\rello";
Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile(reg).matcher(str);
while (m1.find()) {
  System.out.println(m1.group());
}
```

---

I think the answer is :

---

```
h

ello
```

---

but the answer is :

---

```
ello
```

---

Comment: I want to know why the result is different from what i think，and i want to know what i need to know to solve my douts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because that is what the `\r` character does. On some consoles, `\r` "deletes everything on that line before it".

If you print:

```
System.out.println("a\rb");
```

You'll only see `b`.

Your regex indeed matches `h\rello`, and it is indeed printed by `System.out.println`, but since `\r` deletes everything before it, you only see `ello`.

You can see the individual characters that the regex has matched by doing:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m1.group().chars().toArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my doubts. This answer is very helpful to me.

Comment: This is just wild +1.  Do you have any documentation reference?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately, I don't. All I know is that `\r` behaves the same on my OS. I don't know whether it's an OS issue, or a JVM-specific thing, or something else.

Comment: My guess is that it's the console/OS.  Newlines on Linux are just `\n`, while on Windows they are `\r\n`.  Perhaps then `\r` does something differently on Linux.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, I'm on a Mac. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025868/what-is-the-meaning-r-carriage-return-and-f-form-feed-in-java/19025917#19025917), which might be useful. It's probably due to the fact that IDEs behave differently from real consoles. I mean `abc\eb` should in theory look like `bbc`, but on my IDE console it's just `b`.